# rails object id exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There is an `Article` table in my *Rails* app, but in this table, there are hundreds of records that being transferred form and old website, so the table looks like this:

> **1...700** (now use index) ...**empty**... **1001...3000** (old articles ids)

if I generate a new article, article id will be `701`.

But I can't check whether the article id has been used or not until I process `@article.save`.

A temporary solution is: displaying the `ID` column, when a user generates result error, then they enter `id+1` and try to save.

How can I check this status automatically?

The condition is:

If the article id has been used, then check id+1, until finding an id that can be used?

Comment: Model ID field in Postgres is defined by sequence. Just set the beginning of the sequence to hire numbers (migration , of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i was you, I would create and immediately delete all records up to the ids you have already hardcoded from your old app. this way you will continue new ids from the place where old app has left off. I see no reason to make your code more complicated than it needs to be because of the issue that will be literally one-off event.

rails c

```
(700..3000).each do
     a = Article.create() rescue nil #when you hit the ids that are already in the database
     puts a.try(:id) 
     a.delete
 end
```

Comment: but old records is using, because we change our website from asp.net to rails, so I can't delete those record, I just can use skip and move next to find next calid id.

Comment: dont delete them. if you have loaded them with someSQL command they are good to go. Simply go to your terminal and create articles to fill the gap, and then delete them. Postgres should take care of the rest

Comment: ok, so you mean just skip this gap, let id jump to 3001, and no need to worry about this problem, maybe it is a good solution...

Comment: I actually had this problem before.You need to make sure you attempt to create each id until 3001 otherwise with each attempt you will have exception. Code sample should work

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses a sequence to pick the next value for your id column. It sounds like your import process  is not updating the sequence. You can update the value of the sequence with something like this

```
select setval('articles_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles));
```

You can check the name of the sequence from psql with `\d articles`.